# Why this syntax error is coming internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584 throw err; ^?

Tags: node.js

I am very new to node.js, I am trying to write post and get Api's but I am getting this syntax error. Please help me how to overcome this error
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
    throw err;
    ^
    (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)

This is db.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/jobsdb', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connected')
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

This is job.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const JobsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    description: String,
    minbudget: { type: Number, default: 0, min: 0 },
    maxbudget: { type: Number, required: true },
    location: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    country: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    expireOn: { type: Date, required: true }
});

const Jobs = mongoose.model('job', JobsSchema);
module.exports = Jobs;
```

This is Form.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('./models/db');
const Jobs = require('./models/job');
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())


app.post('/api/jobs', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    if (+req.body.minbudget > +req.body.maxbudget) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Enter Valid Budget' })
    }


    const doc = new Jobs(req.body);

    try {
        const result = await doc.save();
        res.json(result);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
    }

});



app.get('/api/jobs', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const results = await Jobs.find({});
        res.json(results);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
    }
});


app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log('Server Started')
});
```

This is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "api-jobs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "jobs.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.9"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some details about the other libraries you're using? It looks like a package that's you've included, or that is perhaps a dependency of one you've included. Please also cut out some irrelevant code, so you can format the error as code without running into the "your post is mostly code" error. Getting the error formatted will make it more readable & that'll be more helpful at this point than your mongoose schema, I expect.

Comment: Hi @ebbishop this is my package.json file {
  "name": "api-jobs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "jobs.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.9"
  }
}